# google cloud datalab: reload set from bigquery leads to RespondNotReady

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Using Datalab for analysis, I need to sample data from bigquery. When I refresh my sample, I sometimes get this error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.pyc in getresponse(self, buffering)
   1059         #
   1060         if self.__state != _CS_REQ_SENT or self.__response:
-> 1061             raise ResponseNotReady()
   1062 
   1063         args = (self.sock,)

ResponseNotReady:
```

This behaviour happens randomly while iterating (100 iterations).

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

That is probably the underlying socket closing. I've opened https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/issues/707 to track. Thanks!